# linux proc fs documentation

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have a driver that raises some warnings/errors during compilation, since the `proc_fs` api changed since its creation. The driver still uses `create_proc_entry` while the latest api version I am aware off, offers `proc_create`. Since I am new to driver programming under linux I tried to look at the source, however my ctags skills must be lacking since I only found `proc_create` in `proc_fs.h`. However, I would like to look at the implementation or some documentation, to know what error codes it returns so I know what I have to handle.

Can you point me to documentation for the proc api, or the source holding the *definition* of proc_create? A hint how it can be found would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create_proc is defined as an inline function, so it is fully implemented in the header [proc_fs.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/proc_fs.h#L30). It basically calls proc_create_data with a NULL for the data argument.

There seems very little documentation on these functions in the source so I'd recommend looking at other call sites within the kernel source, which you cam see listed in this [LXR search](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=proc_create).

BTW, creating new files in /proc seems frowned upon these days - it seems [sysfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt) is where new interfaces should be created.

Answer (score 0):

Best documentation for an API would be existing code itself. Check a few c files in fs/proc or grep for proc_create in the source code